# Free up used Memory

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, memory

When using FunctionCompile[] to generate a large matrix of ranges there seems to be no way of recovering memory even though the variables are either out of scope or overwritten. I am aware that there are more convenient ways to program this example to reduce memory used but that is not the point. I think this has been asked before but I cannot find reference to any solution.

````
$HistoryLength = 0;
In[1]:= range$F = Function[{
    Typed[syst, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 4]],
    Typed[anten, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 2]]},
   
   
   Module[{Nsx, Nsy, Nsz, Nant, reconIndex},
    
    {Nsx, Nsy, Nsz} = Dimensions[syst][[;; 3]];
    Nant = Length[anten];
    
    Table[
     Table[
      Norm[anten[[m]] - syst[[i, j, k]]], {i, Nsx}, {j, Nsy}, {k, 
       Nsz}], {m, Nant}]
    
    ]
   
   ];

In[2]:= rng = FunctionCompile[range$F];

In[3]:= system = 
  CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0.0, 1.0}, {1, 1.5}, {0.0, 1.0}}, {0.02, 
    0.02, 0.02}];

In[4]:= antenna = Flatten[Array[0.1 {#1, 0, #2} &, {10, 20}], 1];

In[5]:= MemoryInUse[]

Out[5]= 561133616

In[6]:= calculateRanges = rng[system, antenna];

In[7]:= MemoryInUse[]

Out[7]= 3268975680

In[8]:= calculateRanges = rng[system, antenna];

In[9]:= MemoryInUse[]

Out[9]= 5976556616

In[10]:= calculateRanges =.

In[11]:= MemoryInUse[]

Out[11]= 5976559208
```
````

Comment: Not sure it has to do with `FunctionCompile`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLvEa.png -- A minute or two later: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcT9Y.png (someone took out the garbage, I guess).

Comment: You can try `Share[]`, which gives back something.